# Restart instead shutdown in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

Recently, I upgraded my ubuntu os system 20.04.1 from 18.04. when I click shut down menu it restarts after 3/4 seconds. I need to press the physical switch to shut down my laptop(Hp ProBook 440).how to get rid of this issue?
I also disabled wake on lan option from bios but nothing happened.

Comment: Do you get the same result running `sudo shutdown -h now`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a BIOS/UEFI setting that decides what happens after shutdown. I disabled automatic restart. And I was done.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `shutdown -h now` in console ?